# Ext js combobox does not display all items in menu

Tags: extjs

Can someone tell me how to get rid of the feature that filters combo box items.
when i click on the trigger of the combo, i want to display ALL menu items regardless of what text is already in the box, NOT filtered. I've tried several different config options with no luck.
make sense ?

for example, if i have 'View' as my text in the combo, and i click on the trigger, it will only show 'View1' and 'View2' items, i want it to include all the others...

Thanks!

heres my current config

```
    {
...
   items: [{
   xtype: 'combo',
   id: 'myViewsCombo',
   emptyText: 'Select View',
   selectOnFocus: true,
   listeners: {
   select: function(combo, record, index) {
            L3.handlers.loadView(combo.value);
  }},
   store: ['View1', 'View2','blahblah']
    }]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the setting the 'disableKeyFilter' config option to true.

See the [ext combobox api](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox).

Comment: thanks so much. damn i don't know how many times i went down that page looking for this and didn't see it. now i understand why my wife says I can't find my ass with a flashlight : )

Comment: I had the same issue; thanks so much! (I really wish the docs were easier to use)

Answer (score 4):

Setting `triggerAction: "all"` solved the same problem for me.